Confused in how to do web scraping for the first time
There is a website like bonbast.com and I'm trying to get values but I'm just confused about how to do it. Values should be something like the output of "US Dollar" and "Euro".
My code:
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://bonbast.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

usd1 = soup.find(id="usd1")
print(usd1)

same_val = soup.find_all(class_="same_val")
print(same_val)

the output is blank and not showing the number of the currency. HTML page https://i.imgur.com/NrTaUY8.png

You;ll need to use something like selenium to scrape a page filled by js

I prefer to do it in CLI. so selenium is not a good idea for me.

Selenium is used in CLI

Can you please refer me to an example of how to extract data in Selenium?

BTW it's not possible at all via BeautifulSoup lib?

All the values you are trying to get are provided by JavaScript. BS is unable to get these values because it is just loading the text of the html page, and has no concept of running JS. You will need to use Selenium to fully load the page, including remote scripts,  before you scrape it.

I got it. Thank you.

Regarding your last question. No, BS cannot get the data you want from that page. Look at it like this. Let's say you and I were in some form of chat, and I sent you a python file in the chat. The chat is not going to run the file, it's just going to provide it. This is what happens when you use BS. You are just being served the local file. In no way is it executed. BS does not execute HTML pages, it just knows how to read/parse text files in HTML format.

Check this out...somebody already written some code for the same website you asking for, I tested it ...It gives Currency-Exchange-Rates
https://github.com/drstreet/Currency-Exchange-Rates-Scraper/blob/master/scrapper.py

ProTip: before you even bother scraping pages, visit them in your browser and turn JavaScript off. If the page is missing a bunch of data, that data was provided by JavaScript and you will not be able to use BS to retrieve it. There are sometimes exceptions to this rule, but they are almost always due to a convoluted design, and generally require nonstandard methods to get the data. As an example, I saw a site that was using JS to populate a chart but the JSON for the chart was at the bottom of the page. In that case you just need to grab the JSON. This is not at all common, though.

From the Reference of this Repo - https://github.com/drstreet/Currency-Exchange-Rates-Scraper/blob/master/scrapper.py
Focusing only on the necessary parts to retrieve exchange rates USD and Euro.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

def get_currency_data():
    url = 'https://www.bonbast.com'
    session = requests.Session()
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
        'Referer': url,
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    }

    response = session.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    # Find the script containing the 'param' value
    scripts = soup.find_all('script')
    param = None
    for script in scripts:
        if '$.post' in script.text:
            match = re.search(r'param:\s*"([^"]+)"', script.text)
            if match:
                param = match.group(1)
                break

    if param:
        post_url = url + '/json'
        post_data = {'param': param}

        # Make POST request to fetch the JSON data
        response = session.post(post_url, headers=headers, data=post_data)
        data = response.json()

        # Extract relevant currency data (USD and Euro)
        currencies = {}
        for key, value in data.items():
            if key == 'usd1':  # USD sell price
                currencies['USD_sell'] = value
            elif key == 'usd2':  # USD buy price
                currencies['USD_buy'] = value
            elif key == 'eur1':  # Euro sell price
                currencies['EUR_sell'] = value
            elif key == 'eur2':  # Euro buy price
                currencies['EUR_buy'] = value

        return currencies
    else:
        return {'error': 'Param not found'}

# Execute the function and print the result
result = get_currency_data()
print(result)

output
{'EUR_sell': '68500', 'EUR_buy': '68400', 'USD_sell': '62800', 'USD_buy': '62700'}


That page is filled by Javascript, that's not somthing BS can scrape.
You'll need to use a browser like app like selenium.

Here is an example to only get the #usd1 field:
usd = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#usd1')
print(f"usd: {usd.text}")


To get all the valuta's in the tables, you can use :
rows = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'table.table.table-condensed > tbody > tr > .same_val')
for row in rows:
    print(f"{row.get_attribute('id')}\t{row.text}")

Here a complete example script with the output below
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-search-engine-choice-screen")
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=selenium")
options.add_argument("--headless")

service = Service()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.get('https://bonbast.com/')

time.sleep(1)

try:
    rows = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'table.table.table-condensed > tbody > tr > .same_val')
    for row in rows:
        print(f"{row.get_attribute('id')}\t{row.text}")
except NoSuchElementException:
    print('Could not find rows')

driver.quit()

With the result:
(venv) ➜ python3 ../bonbast.py
usd1    63350
usd2    63250
eur1    69000
eur2    68900
gbp1    82450
gbp2    82250
chf1    73500
chf2    73400
cad1    45950
cad2    45850
aud1    42350
aud2    42250
...


The page you're interested in is driven by JavaScript. BeautifulSoup can't handle that.
However, you could use selenium.
The following code will extract all currencies with their corresponding sell and buy values.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless=true")
url = "https://www.bonbast.com"

def get_text(e):
    return e.get_attribute("textContent").strip()

def group(g, n=3):
    for i in range(0, len(g), n):
        yield [get_text(e) for e in g[i:i+n]]

def css(c):
    return By.CSS_SELECTOR, c

with webdriver.Chrome(options) as driver:
    driver.get(url)
    ae = EC.presence_of_all_elements_located
    for tbody in WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ae(css("table.table-condensed tbody"))):
        for tr in WebDriverWait(tbody, 10).until(ae(css("tr")))[1:]:
            td = WebDriverWait(tr, 10).until(ae(css("td")))[1:]
            for currency, sell, buy in group(td):
                print(f"{currency}, Sell={int(sell):,d}, Buy={int(buy):,d}")

Output:
US Dollar, Sell=63,000, Buy=62,900
Euro, Sell=68,650, Buy=68,550
British Pound, Sell=82,400, Buy=82,200
Swiss Franc, Sell=73,050, Buy=72,950
Canadian Dollar, Sell=45,650, Buy=45,550
Australian Dollar, Sell=42,250, Buy=42,150
Swedish Krona, Sell=6,065, Buy=6,050
Norwegian Krone, Sell=5,815, Buy=5,800
Russian Ruble, Sell=650, Buy=645
Thai Baht, Sell=1,895, Buy=1,890
Singapore Dollar, Sell=48,100, Buy=48,000
Hong Kong Dollar, Sell=8,110, Buy=8,080
Azerbaijani Manat, Sell=37,050, Buy=36,950
10Armenian Dram, Sell=1,625, Buy=1,620
Danish Krone, Sell=9,205, Buy=9,185
UAE Dirham, Sell=17,230, Buy=17,190
10Japanese Yen, Sell=4,220, Buy=4,210
Turkish Lira, Sell=1,840, Buy=1,820
Chinese Yuan, Sell=8,850, Buy=8,830
KSA Riyal, Sell=16,800, Buy=16,700
Indian Rupee, Sell=750, Buy=745
Ringgit, Sell=14,600, Buy=14,500
Afghan Afghani, Sell=925, Buy=920
Kuwaiti Dinar, Sell=205,400, Buy=205,000
100Iraqi Dinar, Sell=4,810, Buy=4,800
Bahraini Dinar, Sell=167,100, Buy=166,600
Omani Rial, Sell=163,650, Buy=163,350
Qatari Riyal, Sell=17,300, Buy=17,200

